# TFS: submit changes done locally in one branch to another branch

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, branch, tfs-power-tools

I made changes to a lot of files, and in the meantime I figured I rather commit this untested code to a yet-to-be-created branch, so that users of the existing code base are not affected.

As I touched really many, many files and created and added new sub-projects etc., I want to avoid copying files and folders manually.

What's the easiest way to get this done in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

This functionality is provided using `tfpt unshelve /migrate`. To use it, follow these steps:

1. Create a shelveset of your changes (from the UI, or `tf shelve . /R`)
2. Create the new branch
3. Download and install the [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f)
4. From a Visual Studio Command Prompt, run the following command: `tfpt unshelve /migrate /source:$/TeamProject/Main /target:$/TeamProject/Beta`

This will essentially re-write the paths in your shelveset to the new branch.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. In the meantime, I did it the hard way. But I don't want to have to do it again, so I'll use your instructions next time.

Comment: Run tfpt unshelve from a mapped directory to avoid 'Unable to determine the workspace'

Comment: Also it is worth mentioning that after issuing this command you will be able to choose which shelveset to move.

Comment: Another "worth mentioning":

If you perform step 4 above and get `An item with the same key has already been added`, make sure you **UNDO** the changes on the source branch first. See [this article](http://www.lemisolutions.co.nz/2013/07/creating-branch-out-of-your-pending.html)

Also, this is confirmed to work with TFS2012

Comment: Visual Studio command prompt wasn't sufficient for me; I had to actually `cd` into a workspace directory, and then do the full `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools\TFPT.EXE" unshelve /migrate /source:$/blah/Trunk /target:$/blah/Branches/blah` Started the installer again and it does appear that I had installed everything fine.

Comment: Can this same process be used in merging from a branch back to main? I'm a little hesitant to try.

Comment: This worked.  I'll just state that I am utterly shocked I needed to install "power tools" to accomplish this!

Comment: If you still get 'An item with the same key has already been added', make sure you undo all pending changes across all branches, per http://stackoverflow.com/a/26430948/265570

Comment: [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) command to install TFPT and add it to your system PATH: `cinst tfpt`

Comment: This no longer works. TFPT.exe is no more. Any idea how to do this now?