# Visual Studio 2015 - Check in to a different branch in TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I checked out some files from the main branch of our code set in TFS.  Later, a separate branch was created.  I would like to check in my code to the new branch, even though I originally checked it out of the original one.  Is this possible?

EDIT:  I know I can check in to the main branch and do a merge, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, it's based on which version control you are using.

If you are using **GIT,** it's simple. After you created the new branch in the UI, you just need to do a 'check out' of the new branch. Any uncommitted changes will be automatically point to the new branch. You can then commit them there.

If you are using **TFVC**, you need to **shelve your changes on the original branch and unshelve them on the other branch**. This functionality is provided using `tfpt unshelve /migrate` command. More detail steps please refer the question: [TFS: submit changes done locally in one branch to another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923485/tfs-submit-changes-done-locally-in-one-branch-to-another-branch)

It's also a sample which shows the difference between GIT and TFVC.

Comment: I hate Microsoft. Why wouldn't they support this basic functionality?

Answer (score 9):

1. Install [TFS 2015 Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1)
2. Create a shelveset of your changes
3. Open the Developer Command Prompt
4. Use the `tfpt unshelve /migrate` command as such

   `tfpt unshelve /migrate /source:$/Project/Branch1 /target:$/Project/Branch2`

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't do with the answers using Power Tools, so I checked in on the source branch, merged to target, and rolled back from source branch.